# border-radius on only image not support in opera

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>opera border radius</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        img{
            border-radius:10px; 
            -o-border-radius:10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg/450px-Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg" width="337" height="450" alt="my think">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera doesn't like adding border-radius to images directly -- Opera is stubborn like that.

For a solution that works in Opera, check out http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2010/10/border-radius-rounded-images-and-avatars/

Also, put the real CSS rule `border-radius` *after* the vendor-prefixed rule `-o-border-radius`.

Comment: @vipul is as simple as copy/paste jsbin.com/exexer – this is right answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-border-background-boxshadow/#border-radius

Border-radius has had issues in opera, since quite some time. In latest versions, if supported 
can be used directly using  border-radius property.

Officially, Border radius property is supported by all Opera versions > 10.5, but NOT on Opera Mini, and Opera Mobile < 11, but seems to give problems.

(Also, tag this question under css3)

[**EDIT**]
I just checked your code again. You wanted to appy border-radius to an image. This is not possible in Opera, unless you put it as a background-image using css instead of foreground one.

So to get this done, make a div and apply the rounded corners to the div instead of the img.
then set the background-image as the image, you should get the rounded corners. In case the image doesn't come centered, just change position property. That should do the trick.

Here, try this : http://jsfiddle.net/c8nmZ/5/

Comment: i use opera 11.51 but not support border-radius. please try my code and help me (border-radius not support only image)